# Index number where the value of columns of two different dataframes are equal

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two dataframes:

```
Df1 = pd.DataFrame({'street1': ['1, 2', '1, 3', '1, 4', '123']})                    
Df2 = pd.DataFrame({'street2': ['1, 1', '1, 2', '1, 2']})
```

I added a column that tells me if the values of Df1 are in Df2 with the following code.

```
Df1["InDf2"] = Df1.street1.isin(Df2.street2).astype('bool')
```

I need to make another column `Df1['Df2Index']`, containing the index number (or numbers) where Df2 is equal to Df1. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reset the index of the second DataFrame to get the index as a column. then merge on the desired columns. after that drop the extra column and NaNs created in the other columns.

```
Df1 = Df1\
    .merge(Df2.reset_index(), how='outer', right_on='street2', left_on='street1')\
    .drop('street2', axis=1)\
    .dropna(subset=['street1'])
```

output:

```
  street1  InDf2  index
0    1, 2   True    1.0
1    1, 2   True    2.0
2    1, 3  False    NaN
3    1, 4  False    NaN
4     123  False    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

lambda function helps to do that

```
l = df2['street2'].values
df1['InDf2'] = df1.apply(lambda row: 'True' + '-' +str(list(df2[df2['street2'] == row['street1']].index.values)) if row['street1'] in l else 'False-Not Exist', axis = 1)
df1[['InDf2', 'Df2_index']] = df1['InDf2'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df1

    street1 InDf2   Df2_index
0   1, 2    True    [1, 2]
1   1, 3    False   Not_Exist
2   1, 4    False   Not_Exist
3   123     False   Not_Exist
```

Comment: apply should be avoided whenever possible. it doesn't take advantage of vectorization and returns a new dataframe (which has an IO overhead). when a dataframe is big, it's considerably slower than vectorized functions.